replication slot's wal_status reserved vs extended
When queried using
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots ;
There's one more column as wal_status which has can be mainly either reserved vs extended.
what is the main difference?
will one has higher precedence to provide reliability ?

Have the considered the documentation?

thanks @jjanes. Do you know if slot grows more than max_wal_size, then what will happen in case of reserved?

Unless max_slot_wal_keep_size is in use, nothing will happen.  It will continue to be reserved.  Eventually you will run out of disk space (if the slot doesn't start advancing first).
